# 70’s children’s book about a boy with a magic can of paint

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

This was a book I read as small child. A little boy has a magic can of paint. When he first paints with it the colors are terrible. Then when the sun rises the next morning it is beautiful.

A king hires him to paint his castle. It looks terrible and the king is about to punish him! Then the sun rises and the castle looks splendid.

Comment: Hello Ed. Is there anything else you might remember about this book? No detail is too small. Please [edit] them in. For instance, when did you read it?

Comment: I remember [one about magic _chalk_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Chalk)...